# Access a list of dictionaries inside of a dictionary in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to access a list inside of my Django Html template, but I can't seem to grab the first element of the list the normal way by grabbing it via its index. In my views, I have a function `edamam` that calls the API endpoint and returns a JSON dictionary named `ingredients`.

Here's the function:

```
@login_required
def edamam(request):
    ingredients = {}
    if 'ingr' in request.GET:
        ingr = request.GET['ingr']
        app_key = APP_KEY
        app_id = APP_ID
        url = f'https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/v2/parser?ingr={ingr}&app_id={app_id}&app_key={app_key}'
        response = requests.get(url)
        ingredients = response.json()
        print(f'Type: {type(ingredients)}')
        return render(request, 'todo/edamam.html', {'ingredients': ingredients})
    else:
        return render(request, 'todo/edamam.html', {'error': 'That item does not exist in the database.'})
```

I printed `typeof(ingredients)` to be certain I'm returning a dictionary and the printout does verify that in the console:

```
Type: <class 'dict'>
```

In my views `edamam.html`, I'm grabbing `ingredients.parsed` (ingredients is just a massive dictionary) because I'm trying to get the list named `parsed` in order to grab elements from that.

```
<div class="col-md-5">
   {% if ingredients %}
   <p>{{ ingredients.parsed }}</p>
   {% endif %} {% endblock %}
</div>
```

which returns:

```
[{'food': 

    {'foodId': 'food_bnxr4n3b1ld7i6ace2hkqbwm89du', 'label': 'cheeseburger', 'nutrients': {'ENERC_KCAL': 263.0, 'PROCNT': 12.97, 'FAT': 11.79, 'CHOCDF': 27.81, 'FIBTG': 1.1}
    , 'category': 'Generic foods', 'categoryLabel': 'food'}

}]
```

My question is, how do I get to the 'food' dictionary inside of list? I tried `ingredients.parsed.food` (nothing returns) and also tried `ingredients.parsed['food']` and get a template syntax error
`Could not parse the remainder: '['food']' from 'ingredients.parsed['food']'` and lastly `ingredients.parsed[0]` since it is the first element in the `parsed` list, but I get another template syntax error `Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'ingredients.parsed[0]'`. So ultimately I'm just trying to grab the `nutrients` dictionary items inside of the `food` dictionary which seems to be the first element of the `parsed` dictionary. I'm just not certain how to get to `food` yet.

Comment: If you're only ever going to return one element, then don't return the list, but return the element. If you're going to support more than one element, then use a second for loop. Hardcoded indexes, while they work are bad design in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work,

```
ingredients.parsed.0
```

try it!